# remove pixel annotations in dicom image

Tags: python, image, numpy, image-processing, dicom

I am analyzing medical images. All images have a marker with the position. It looks like this
[image]

It is the "TRH RMLO" annotation in this image, but it can be different in other images. Also the size varies. The image is cropped but you see that the tissue is starting on the right side.
I found that the presence of these markers distort my analysis.

How can I remove them?

I load the image in python like this

```
import dicom
import numpy as np

img = dicom.read_file(my_image.dcm)
img_array = img.pixel_array
```

The image is then a numpy array. The white text is always surrounded by a large black area (black has value zero). The marker is in a different position in each image.

How can I remove the white text without hurting the tissue data.

**UPDATE**

added a second image

[image]

**UPDATE2**:
Here are two of the original dicom files. All personal information has been removed.edit:removed

Comment: So all the markers are of different scales, and in different places?

Comment: @bjd2385 yes, they are in different positions with different sizes. The marker always looks similar but with slightly different text (e.g. for left/right)

Comment: Can you share the original DICOM images please?

Comment: @MarkSetchell I added one of the original dicom files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the actual pixel values of the image you supplied, you can see that the marker is almost (99.99%) pure white and this doesn't occur elsewhere in the image so you can isolate it with a simple 99.99% threshold.

I prefer **ImageMagick** at the command-line, so I would do this:

```
convert sample.dcm -threshold 99.99% -negate mask.png
```

[image]

```
convert sample.dcm mask.png -compose darken -composite result.jpg
```

[image]

Of course, if the sample image is not representative, you may have to work harder. Let's look at that...

If the simple threshold doesn't work for your images, I would look at *"Hit and Miss Morphology"*. Basically, you threshold your image to pure black and white - at around 90% say, and then you look for specific shapes, such as the corner markers on the label. So, if we want to look for the top-left corner of a white rectangle on a black background, and we use `0` to mean *"this pixel must be black"*, `1` to mean *"this pixel must be white"* and `-` to mean *"we don't care"*, we would use this pattern:

```
0 0 0 0 0
0 1 1 1 1
0 1 - - -
0 1 - - -
0 1 - - -
```

Hopefully you can see the top left corner of a white rectangle there. That would be like this in the Terminal:

```
convert sample.dcm -threshold 90% \
  -morphology HMT '5x5:0,0,0,0,0 0,1,1,1,1 0,1,-,-,- 0,1,-,-,- 0,1,-,-,-' result.png
```

Now we also want to look for top-right, bottom-left and bottom-right corners, so we need to rotate the pattern, which **ImageMagick** handily does when you add the `>` flag:

```
convert sample.dcm -threshold 90% \
   -morphology HMT '5x5>:0,0,0,0,0 0,1,1,1,1 0,1,-,-,- 0,1,-,-,- 0,1,-,-,-' result.png
```

[image]

Hopefully you can see dots demarcating the corners of the logo now, so we could ask **ImageMagick** to trim the image of all extraneous black and just leave the white dots and then tell us the bounding box:

```
cconvert sample.dcm -threshold 90% \
   -morphology HMT '5x5>:0,0,0,0,0 0,1,1,1,1 0,1,-,-,- 0,1,-,-,- 0,1,-,-,-' -format %@ info:
308x198+1822+427
```

So, if I now draw a red box around those coordinates, you can see where the label has been detected - of course in practice I would draw a black box to cover it but I am explaining the idea:

```
convert sample.dcm -fill "rgba(255,0,0,0.5)" -draw "rectangle 1822,427 2130,625" result.png
```

[image]

If you want a script to do that automagically, I would use something like this, saving it as `HideMarker`:

```
#!/bin/bash
input="$1"
output="$2"

# Find corners of overlaid marker using Hit and Miss Morphology, then get crop box
IFS="x+" read w h x1 y1 < <(convert "$input" -threshold 90% -morphology HMT '5x5>:0,0,0,0,0 0,1,1,1,1 0,1,-,-,- 0,1,-,-,- 0,1,-,-,-' -format %@ info:)

# Calculate bottom-right corner from top-left and dimensions
((x1=x1-1))
((y1=y1-1))
((x2=x1+w+1))
((y2=y1+h+1))
convert "$input" -fill black -draw "rectangle $x1,$y1 $x2,$y2" "$output"
```

Then you would do this to make it executable:

```
chmod +x HideMarker
```

And run it like this:

```
./HideMarker someImage.dcm  result.png
```

Comment: this sounds like a great idea as I already convert the images from dcm to png with imagemagick. So what would be solution for the convert command line that does generalize to different image sizes and different positions? I will test these on a small sample of my dcm files to check.

Comment: Ok, I have added a script.

Comment: Unfortunately, this already fails for a lot of images. Maybe it is because of more pure white areas in these pictures. I added a failing dicom in the description above

Comment: Try increasing the threshold to 99%.

Comment: that works, nice!. By the way, how do I efficiently convert a folder of dcm images to png? When I do convert *.dcm *.png my RAM is filling up and it eventually stalls my system. I usually do it on our server with plenty of RAM, but there must be a better way.

Comment: If you are not using my script, do `magick mogrify -format png *dcm`

Comment: Or use **homebrew** to install **GNU Parallel** and then do them all in parallel with `parallel convert {} {}.png ::: *.dcm`

Comment: Or, if you are using my script, `parallel ./HideMarker {} {.}.png ::: *dcm`

Comment: thank you very much! I had to raise the threshold to 99.99% but now my test sample of 100 images works fine

Comment: I refined this further. On a larger test sample I could further reduce errors by extending the 5x5 pattern to a 8x8 pattern. But using the 8x8 pattern my results still show the edges of the marker. How can I remove these? I changed these parts in the script: ((x1=x1-1)) to ((x1=x1-30)) but they are still visible. I do not want to was too much space because in others images the marker partly overlaps the tissue.

Answer (score 2):

I have another idea. This solution is in OpenCV using python. It is a rather solution.

1. First, obtain the binary threshold of the image.

   `ret,th = cv2.threshold(img,2,255, 0)`
   [image]
2. Perform morphological dilation:

`dilate = cv2.morphologyEx(th, cv2.MORPH_DILATE, kernel, 3)`
[image]

3. To join the gaps, I then used median filtering:

`median = cv2.medianBlur(dilate, 9)`
[image]

Now you can use the contour properties to eliminate the smallest contour and retain the other containing the image.

It also works for the second image:

[image]

Comment: very nice, thanks. However, there are a few images where the marker is overlapping with the tissue. It doesn't work there.

Comment: @spore234 Oh I didn't know that. How will you proceed in those cases? Have you thought about analyzing the FFT spectrum of these images? Maybe if there is a correlation in the phase spectrum in all the images, they can be knocked off so that when we perform inverse FFT we are left with only the tissue portion.

Comment: The solution I accepted puts a black square on this area that partly overlaps with the tissue. This is OK for the few cases where it happens. Your solution would blacken the whole image I guess.

Answer (score 1):

If these annotations are in the DICOM file there are a couple ways they could be stored (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/4857782/1901261). The currently supported method can be cleaned off by simply removing the 60xx group attributes from the files.

For the deprecated method (which is still commonly used) you can clear out the unused high bit annotations manually without messing up the other image data as well. Something like:

```
int position = object.getInt( Tag.OverlayBitPosition, 0 );
if( position == 0 ) return;

int bit = 1 << position;
int[] pixels = object.getInts( Tag.PixelData );
int count = 0;
for( int pix : pixels )
{
   int overlay = pix & bit;
   pixels[ count++ ] = pix - overlay;
}
object.putInts( Tag.PixelData, VR.OW, pixels );
```

If these are truly burned into the image data, you're probably stuck using one of the other recommendations here.

Comment: I think it is burned in. I added one of the original dicom files to the description.

Answer (score 0):

The good thing is, that these watermarks are probably in an isolated totally black are which makes it easier (although it's questionable if removing this is according to the indicated usage; license-stuff).

Without beeing an expert, here is one **idea**. It might be a sketch of some very very powerful approach tailored to this problem but you have to decide if implementation-complexity & algorithmic-complexity (very dependent on image-statistics) are worth it:

#### Basic idea

- Detect the semi-cross like borders (4)
- Calculate the defined rectangle from these
- Black-out this rectangle

#### Steps

0

Binarize

1

- Use some gradient-based edge-detector to get all the horizontal edges
- There may be multiple; you can try to give min-length (maybe some morphology needed to connect pixels which are not connected based on noise in source or algorithm)

2

- Use some gradient-based edge-detector to get all the horizontal edges
- Like the above, but a different orientation

3

- Do some connected-component calculation to get some objects which are vertical and horizontal lines
- Now you can try different chosings of candidate-components (8 real ones) with the following knowledge

  - two of these components can be described by the same line (slope-intercept form; linear regression problem) -> line which borders the rectangle
  - it's probably that the best 4 pair-chosings (according to linear-regression loss) are the valid borders of this rectangle
  - you might add the assumption, that vertical borders and horizontal borders are orthogonal to each other

4 
- Calculate the rectangle from these borders
- Widen it by a few pixels (hyper-parameter)
- Black-out that rectangle

That's the basic approach.

#### Alternative

This one is much less work, use more specialized tools and assumes the facts in the opening:

- the stuff to remove is on some completely black part of the image
- it's kind of isolated; distance to medical-data is high

Steps

- Run some general OCR to detect characters
- Get the occupied pixels / borders somehow (i'm not sure what OCR tools return)
- Calculate some outer rectangle and black-out (using some predefined widening-gap; this one needs to be much bigger than the one above)

#### Alternative 2

Sketch only: The idea is to use something like [binary-closing](http://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.morphology.html#binary-closing) on the image somehow to build fully connected-components ouf of the source pixels (while small gaps/holes are filled), so that we got one big component describing the medical-data and one for the watermark. Then just remove the smaller one.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure this can be optimized, but ... You could create 4 patches of size 3x3 or 4x4, and initialize them with the exact content of the pixel values for each of the individual corners of the frame surrounding the annotation text. You could then iterate over the whole image (or have some smart initialization looking only in the black area) and find the exact match for those patches. It is not very likely you will have the same regular structure (90 deg corner surrounded by near 0) in the tissue, so this might give you the bounding box.

Comment: It's a goof start, but don't forget the multiple size issue.

Answer (score -1):

Simpler one is still possible!!!.

Just implement following after (img_array = img.pixel_array)

img_array[img_array > X] = Y

In which X is the intensity threshold you want to eliminate after that. Also Y is the intensity value which you want to consider instead of that.

For example:
img_array[img_array > 4000] = 0

Replace white matter greater than 4000 with black intensity 0.