# find coordinates of small partially-transparent image within a large image

Tags: python, image, compare, imagemagick, command-line-interface

I am looking for a way to programmatically (without using any graphical user interface) find the coordinates of a small image within a large image.

My aim is to find the coordinates of small `corner images` within a larger information image. With these coordinates I want to determine specific "regions of interest" so that I would be able to focus on these regions while presenting the image or cut these regions from the image.

The described `corner images` could look like these (please ignore the blue numbers, as they are only comments. I'd like to use gray PNG graphics with transparency):
[image]
`1` top left corner
`2` bottom left corner
`3` bottom right corner
`4` top right corner

These `corner images` are placed at certain positions within the large image:
[image]
Each set of `corner icons` defines a "region of interest" (how to determine which of the multiple top left corners belongs to which region would be another issue, though).

I'd like to use a free/open source library together with command line operation or a Python interface. It seems that the `ImageMagick` library looks pretty close to a possible solution. But any other technology would be fine if it solves this problem.

With e.g. the `ImageMagick` library I would like to check the four `corner items` sequentially (they are just 90 degree rotations of the same original image) and "compare" each of them with the large image. Within the large image, it would be more than possible that the `corner items` reside "very near" to other graphical content. So, a simple block-wise identity testing would possibly fail. "Transparency" should be considered as "don't care".

What tool and process could I use to get the absolute x- and y-positions of such a small image within a larger one?

Comment: This is extremely similar... http://stackoverflow.com/a/41761313/2836621

Comment: Please provide some sample images so we can see what you mean.

Comment: @Mark: Yes, indeed, my question could hopefully be solved by methods you mentioned in your answer to the other question. I will try it and get back here.

Comment: @Mark: the pictures show the types of images I am operating on. They are hand drawings and thus don't look like medical images. In order to keep the corner images identical, I copy/paste them from a self made icon library.

Comment: Ok, I see. I have some questions... have you already marked the images or are you planning to mark them when you have a method? Are the images and corner markers JPG or PNG files? Are the corners ever rotated at all? Could the corners be detected by the presence of a certain unique colour not occurring in the informational image - as that would be much faster? What is the transparency issue - could you clarify - are the images/corners already semi-transparent or do you want to make them that way?

Comment: I already marked a lot of images like this but I would erase and redo the marking when a suitable method requires so. I generally use PNG files as they don't deteriorate in quality when changed and re-saved. The corners are not to be rotated different than in 90 degrees. Currently, all the corners have a static grayish color. Within the informational image, there are some other "comments" which are drawn with the same color. I use transparency "between" the informational parts of the drawings. So any space which is `white`, here, is in fact transparent within the PNG file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finding shapes in images is quite hard and can take quite a long time because you end up trying to match the shape at each and every pixel position of your large image and that involves many multiplications and comparisons. By comparison, finding a colour is relatively simple, so I would suggest you consider using saturated colour-coded markers instead and, as your drawings a by hand, they are pretty unlikely to occur in your drawings.

So, maybe something along these lines for (top-left `tl.png`, top-right `tr.png`, bottom-left `bl.png` and bottom-right `br.png`):

```
convert -size 24x24 xc:none -background grey -gravity northwest -splice 1x1 -fill magenta -draw "point 0,0" tl.png
```

[image]

```
convert -size 24x24 xc:none -background grey -gravity northeast -splice 1x1 -fill cyan -draw "point 24,0" tr.png
```

[image]

```
convert -size 24x24 xc:none -background grey -gravity southeast -splice 1x1 -fill yellow -draw "point 24,24" br.png
```

[image]

```
convert -size 24x24 xc:none -background grey -gravity southwest -splice 1x1 -fill blue -draw "point 0,24" bl.png
```

[image]

Hopefully, you can see cyan, magenta, yellow and blue markers in each corner and that the grey visual effect you had before is retained. Here they are blown up:

[image]

Then if you have an image like this:

[image]

You can easily find corners with:

```
convert z.png txt: | grep -E "cyan|magenta|yellow|blue"
```

**Output**

```
11,11: (65535,0,65535)  #FFFF0000FFFF  magenta
380,11: (0,65535,65535)  #0000FFFFFFFF  cyan
11,180: (0,0,65535)  #00000000FFFF  blue
380,180: (65535,65535,0)  #FFFFFFFF0000  yellow
11,201: (65535,0,65535)  #FFFF0000FFFF  magenta
355,201: (0,65535,65535)  #0000FFFFFFFF  cyan
11,365: (0,0,65535)  #00000000FFFF  blue
355,365: (65535,65535,0)  #FFFFFFFF0000  yellow
```

For added certainty of the markers not occurring in your image, you could add a second, unlikely colour beside the cyan, magenta, yellow corner pixels that you fell back on to be certain to have found a marker - say a red and a green then the odds of that occurring naturally in your image would be infinitesimal.

---

If you want to compare a shape-matching approach, you could flatten my `tl.png` (top-left) onto a white background like this:

```
convert tl.png -background white -flatten x.png
```

and do a sub-image search like this:

```
compare  -metric RMSE -subimage-search z.png x.png locations.png
2208.73 (0.0337031) @ 11,11
```

and you will see it takes 11 seconds and generates these two images:

[image]

and

[image]

which show where the match is found and the percentage certainty of the match.

P.S. I made the large picture with this:

```
convert -size 600x400 xc:white -draw "image over 10,10 35,35 'tl.png'" -draw "image over 355,10 25,25 'tr.png'" -draw "image over 10,155 25,25 'bl.png'" -draw "image over 355,155 25,25 'br.png'" -draw "image over 10,200 35,35 'tl.png'" -draw "image over 330,200 25,25 'tr.png'" -draw "image over 10,340 25,25 'bl.png'" -draw "image over 330,340 25,25 'br.png'" -bordercolor black -border 1 z.png
```